# I can't trace this pointer to pointer array program

Tags: c++, initialization, implicit-conversion, string-literals, pointer-to-pointer

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
char* str[]={"Man","Woman","Car","Plane",0};
int main(){
char** cp=str;
while(*cp!=0)
cout<<*cp++<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

It prints the String.
But when I print **cp++ I get only first letters like M,W,C,P.

Comment: And what is the issue exactly?

Comment: I know you didn't cut and paste your code because of the typo. `court`.

Comment: Sorry I didn't wrong in ide

Comment: It would be useful if you clearly explained what your program is trying to do and what the issue is.

Comment: I simply want to know why the output is not the same when I use **cp++

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  The code presented produces the output you presumably expect.  Different code produces different output.  What's surprising about that?

Comment: You want to know why cout prints a `char*` as a string but a `char` as a character? What do you expect it to do?

Comment: Yes you right .But I want to know how **cp++ works here.

Comment: @Harrisonwells _"But I want to know how **cp++ works here."_ Well it prints single characters as expected?

Comment: `(*cp++)` is a `char*` (string).  `*(*cp++)` is a `char` (the first character of the string at `(*cp++)`).

Answer (score 2):

For starters the array should be declared with the qualifier `const` because in C++ string literals have types of constant character arrays.

```
const char* str[]={"Man","Woman","Car","Plane",0};
```

In fact the declaration above is equivalent to

```
const char* str[]={ &"Man"[0], &"Woman"[0], &"Car"[0], &"Plane"[0], 0 };
```

because the string literals having array types used as initializers in this declaration are implicitly converted to pointers to their first elements.

In this declaration

```
char** cp=str;
```

that also should be written like

```
const char** cp=str;
```

the pointer `cp` points to the first element of the array that has the type char * and points to the first character of the string literal `"Man"`.

Dereferencing the pointer `cp` one time like `*cp` you will get the first element of the array that has the pointer type `char *` and points to the character `'M'` of the string literal `"Man"`. Dereferencing the pointer the second time like `**cp` you will get an object of the type `char` that contain this character `'M'`.